# gcloud compute error: "More than one Autoscaler with given targe."

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

This command used to work (around May 2016) but for some reason it does not anymore:

```
gcloud compute --verbosity error --project ""phantomjscloud-20160125"" instance-groups managed list
```

I now get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.list) More than one
>   Autoscaler with given targe.

I can't find any details regarding this error.  What changed, and how do I again properly enumerate my instance groups?

Given that all my instance groups use (and have always used) autoscaling I'm not sure why I am now getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the root cause was, but I deleted an instance group with a very similar name to another one `ez-deploy-pjsc-api-preempt-large-usa-central1-a-1` vs `ez-deploy-pjsc-api-preempt-large-usa-central1-a`  and now it works.

Seems like a bug in the gcloud system.

Comment: If you can still reproduce this issue, kindly open an issue report on [gcloud issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) with detailed information and reproduction steps. Once done let me know so that I can forward it to engineering team. Thanks